# What is happening in this while loop?

Tags: python

I'm using this function to get the prime factors of the a number. The current output is printing each prime factor. I'm trying to understand the workings of this code, and I don't understand how the `while` loop is working.

```
def get_primes(n):
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        while n % i == 0:
            n = n / i
            print(i)

print(get_primes(32))
```

The output is the correct answer, `2 2 2 2 2`. But I don't understand how `2` is the only value of `i` where `n % i == 0`.

Comment: Because that's the prime factorization of 32. Try it with a different number (for example 60) and you'll get a different result.

Comment: The while loop is printing `i` multiple times when `i == 2` because: `32 % 2 == 0` so `n` becomes `32 / 2 == 16` and it prints `i` which is `2`. Then `16 % 2 == 0` which keeps the while condition true, so `n` becomes `16 / 2 == 8` and it prints `i` again which is still `2`, and so on.

Comment: to understand better what is happening in your code you can add a print(n) after doing n = n/i in the while loop, this will help you see how n changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through your code line by line :D

```
def get_primes(n):              # great use of a function :D
    for i in range(2, n + 1):   # this loops through the possible factors
        while n % i == 0:       # this loops through n, trying to factor it
            n = n / i           # these only run if i is a factor of n
            print(i)            # note that n = n/i only runs when i is a factor
                                # meaning it divides for the upcoming iterations
```

Your code runs perfectly fine. Because `i` is 2 from the start of the for loop, we'll examine the code from it. When the function gets to the `while` loop, it checks if `n%i == 0`, which when `i` is 2 means if `n%2 == 0`. When `n` is even, the `n = n/i` will run. It'll `print(i)` too. When it goes around the second time, `n` is half the original `n`. Note the `while` loop only runs when `n%i == 0`, meaning `i` needs to be a prime factor. This will find all the prime factors of `n`.

Because 32 is equal to 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 or 2^5, it printed 2 five times. Try something different and you'll see it works :D

Comment: ahh, I feel like an idiot. I wasn't thinking about the     n = n/i     part of the code which  causes n to be reduced. Thank you!

Comment: No need to look down upon yourself. I wouldn't even know how to even start making this. It looks really compact :D

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what the answer is. The primes that multiply to form 32 are 2, 2, 2, 2 and 2.

This is a fact of mathematics; nothing to do with Python.